# error in posting data from jquery to controller

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

Hi iam getting error when i am trying to put ContentType in button click event's ajax call

```
viewmodel = ko.observableArray();
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Render/LoadSurveyQuestions?sg=" + getUrlVars()["g"] + "&stg=" + getUrlVars()["sig"],
        success: function (result) {
            viewmodel = ko.mapping.fromJS(result);
            ko.applyBindings(viewmodel, document.getElementById("tblQuestions"));
        }
    });
    $("#btnNext").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            data: ko.toJSON(viewmodel),
            url: "/Render/SaveSurveyQuestionOptions",
            //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            //   dataType: "json", 
            success: function (result) {}
        });
    });
```

I am using following controller method
for saving list.i am getting error
when calling this method using ajax.

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    [JsonFilter(Param = "listobj", JsonDataType = typeof (List < SurveyQuestion > ))]
    public void SaveSurveyQuestionOptions(List < SurveyQuestion > listobj) {

        if (listobj.Count > 0) {
            foreach(SurveyQuestion objSurveyQuestion in listobj) {
                foreach(SurveyOption objOption in objSurveyQuestion.OptionList) {
                    //if (objOption.OptionSelected)
                    //{
                    //    objSurveyQuestion.OptionId = objOption.OptionID;
                    //    objSurveyQuestion.OptionText = objOption.OptionText;
                    //}
                }
                //osurveymanager.InsertQuestionAnswers(objSurveyQuestion);

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: If only we knew the error.

Comment: i just want to tell that is the place i am getting error in js

Comment: We need to know the server error. Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Or if it's just a js error, what line? What does the console say? There's nothing here that will allow anyone to answer this question.